# Crop image to circle shape for PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I am creating a simple application with PyQt6. I want to my code to automatically crop the selected image into circle shape. How can I do that? Please help

Comment: Why you don't let the PyQt app select the image file and then crop it with [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) and then display the image again in the app?

Comment: Can Pillow library do that?

Comment: Yeb, see [this](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-square-circle-thumbnail/) post.

Answer (score 1):

Using an external library like pillow or opencv makes things easy as they generally have functions that already provide similar processing, but there's no need to add a dependency for simple manipulations like this, unless performance becomes an issue.

On Qt it's pretty straightforward: create a new QPixmap based on the minimum extent (assuming the circle is going to be the biggest possible in a given rectangle), create a QPainterPath with a circle that will be used for *clipping*, and finally draw the source contents in it.

```
def circleImage(imagePath):
    source = QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath)
    size = min(source.width(), source.height())

    target = QtGui.QPixmap(size, size)
    target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

    qp = QtGui.QPainter(target)
    qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
    path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
    path.addEllipse(0, 0, size, size)
    qp.setClipPath(path)

    sourceRect = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, size, size)
    sourceRect.moveCenter(source.rect().center())
    qp.drawPixmap(target.rect(), source, sourceRect)
    qp.end()

    return target
```

This obviously creates an image with transparent background around the circle, you can use any of the [global colors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#GlobalColor-enum) or your own QColor.
Note that, no matter the color, the `fill()` is **mandatory**, otherwise there will probably be random pixels on the unpainted portions of the image instead (usually some "RAM residue").